# Apply image operations on live video (videoinput) in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, video, video-conversion

I am trying to do the operations like `rgb2gray(img)` on a live video read using `vid=videoinput()` like `rgb2gray(vid)`.

It is a type mismatch but I am stuck here. Should I convert the vid to any image format and store it in a matrix or is there any other way like to do `rgb2gray`? I don't want to use `vid.ReturnedColorSpace = 'grayscale'`, as I need to convert the video into images or matrix and do `rgb2gray` operation.

Comment: You could convert each frame individually.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `vid` is a `videoinput` object that lets you capture frames from a camera. You cannot pass it to `rgb2gray`. What you can do is grab the frames one at a time in a loop, and pass each one to `rgb2gray` individually.